# Replace static JSON data with $HTTP request in AngularJS factory

Tags: angularjs, json

Have some troubles with replacing static JSON data in AngularJS factory, here is example with static data:

```
    angular.module('starter.services', [])    
    .factory('catgs', function($http) {
      var catgs = [{
        id: 19,
        name: 'CATG20'
},{
        id: 20,
        name: 'CATG21'
      }];    
      return {
        all: function() {
          return catgs;
        },
        remove: function(catg) {
          catgs.splice(catgs.indexOf(catg), 1);
        },
        get: function(catgId) {
          for (var i = 0; i < catgs.length; i++) {
            if (catgs[i].id === parseInt(catgId)) {
              return catgs[i];
            }
          }
          return null;
        }
      };
    });
```

Need replace static **var catgs** with **$http.get** from json data url. I'm new in Angular and need help with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

you are looking for something like this

```
function getStuff() {

        return $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: '/yourresturl'
        }).then(function successCallback(response) {

            return response;
        }, function errorCallback(response) {
            return ;
           //do something
        });

    }
```

Comment: looking somethink like var catgs = $http.get('http://myurl') .... but this not work and I don't how do it

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
 angular.module('starter.services', [])    
        .factory('catgs', function($http) {
          var catgs =null;    
          return {
            all: function() {
              if(catgs != null)
              return catgs;
              $http.get('myurl').then(function(res){
               catgs=res.data;//
               return catgs;
             })
            },
            remove: function(catg) {
              catgs.splice(catgs.indexOf(catg), 1);
            },
            get: function(catgId) {
              for (var i = 0; i < catgs.length; i++) {
                if (catgs[i].id === parseInt(catgId)) {
                  return catgs[i];
                }
              }
              return null;
            }
          };
        });
```

Comment: Tnx for answer, but something wrong ... As you can see http://1871.by/swipe/www/#/products